# Branch links to download my app on social media (Instagram) posts are not working

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

I am using this branch deeplink:

https://zandumobileclient.app.link/shareapp

which works great when you are in the browser on a mobile device.

BUT

when i use that link inside Instagram like so:

[image]

or any other social media app i get this image:
[image]

Any idea how i can get it to work on Instagram and any other social media app?

Comment: Can you share what's the expected behavior you are looking for?

Comment: hello Kartik, i wanted it to open the appropriate app store, not the fallback web page from Branch.

Comment: This is essentially something called as a Native Link feature. You can easily turn this off from your Dashboard's > Configuration section.

Comment: Hello Kartik, i turned it off and i am still getting this annoying page. It is not even defaulting to my landing page i configured in the branch dashboard.