# Branch link not redirecting to app store even in Safari

Tags: ios, branch.io

Here is the video describing the issue:

https://youtube.com/shorts/u0JbIGEF6j8

On iOS my Branch.io links are not working properly. I turned off native links as people were suggesting this was the case but the camera reading the qr code opens up safari but i still see the branch landing page from this post:

[Branch links to download my app on social media (Instagram) posts are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561153/branch-links-to-download-my-app-on-social-media-instagram-posts-are-not-workin?noredirect=1#comment135385120_76561153)

This is the branch link i am using in the QR code:

https://zandumobileclient.app.link/shareapp

I just want the link to open up the app store if the app is not installed. I don't understand why this is so complicated.

Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So native links inside the configuration panel on branch.io had to be turned off and we needed to wait a while for the change to take effect. We are now good to go. Thanks for the support provided by Branch.io staff.